# Updating mapfish maximum request size in docker

Tags: mapfish, mapfish-print-2

I am using docker map fish for print module. When I am sending the large geojson for print. It returns 400 bad request & I found the size are hardcoded in the https://github.com/mapfish/mapfish-print/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/mapfish/print/servlet/RequestSizeFilter.java.

How do I update MAX_CONTENT_LENGTH dynamically using docker?

```
Request size exceeds limitDescription 
The server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error 

 (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).
```

---

I can directly update the web.xml by volume binding in the docker

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use volume binding to replace the web.xml with our version of web.xml

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).